Estimating mixed model with identical response value but different covariate values within a pair
Say we have a dataset with individuals. Each individual performed a task, either in solo or with another individual (variable condition), and we measured the performance of the whole group, that is, the individual or the pair (variable score). 
In other words, we have one value of score for individuals in solo, and twice the same value for individuals in a pair.
We considered individuals in solo as forming a pair on their own, leading to the variable pair.
We also measured a covariate individually, that is, we have one value of cov for each individual.
The dataframe looks like this:
> head(df, 12)
id  pair score cov condition
1  pair1     3   6      solo
2  pair2     6   4      pair
3  pair2     6   3      pair
4  pair3     3   3      solo
5  pair4     5   3      pair
6  pair4     5   4      pair
7  pair5     3   5      solo
8  pair6     5   5      pair
9  pair6     5   3      pair
10 pair7     4   3      solo
11 pair8     4   5      pair
12 pair8     4   4      pair

Although the score is not repeated, I was wondering whether it made sense to fit a mixed model given that individuals have different values of cov within a pair.
However, estimating a model such as:
lme4::lmer(score ~ condition * cov + (1 | pair))
results in a failure to converge.
I have a feeling that this is to be expected, given the redundancy in the score variable. That said, I cannot quite get the reason why.
I read somewhere that the residual variance could be confounded with the random effect variance. But shouldn't the residual variance be different than the random variance to account for the observed difference in cov ?

It is not a problem per se to have variables that vary at different levels. cov is a "first level" covariate because it varies at the level of individual, and condition is a "second level" covariate because it varies at the level of pair. Some "pairs" have only one individual so you are right to suspect that as the reason for lack of convergence. It may also be due to a relatively small dataset that you are trying to use to estimate a lot of parameters. How many rows are in the dataset?

I might suggest using a Bayesian approach so that you can put an informative prior on the random effect variance component which will help the model converge.

FYI, I have voted to migrate this question to stats.stackexchange.com because it is really about the statistical model and not the R programming.
